# Find the number of permutations $\mid a_1-1 \mid = \mid a_2-2 \mid = \ldots = \mid a_{100}-100 \mid$

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of permutations $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{100}$ of numbers $1, 2, \ldots, 100$ such that 
$$\mid a_1-1 \mid = \mid a_2-2 \mid = \ldots = \mid a_{100}-100 \mid$$

---

My attempt :

Since $(a_1-1)+(a_2-2)+\ldots+(a_{100}-100)=0$

Case 1 :

$a_1-1=0, a_2-2=0, \ldots, a_{100}-100=0$

so $a_1=1, a_2=2, \ldots, a_{100}=100$

The number of permutations = 1

Case 2 :

$a_{i_1} - i_1 = a_{i_2} - i_2 = \ldots = a_{i_{50}} - i_{50} = a $

$a_{i_{51}} - i_{51} = a_{i_{52}} - i_{52} = \ldots = a_{i_{100}} - i_{100} = -a$

The number of ways to choose $\{i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_{50}\} = \binom{100}{50}$

so the number of permutations $= \binom{100}{50}$

Answer : $\binom{100}{50}+1$

Can someone please check if my answer is correct or not ? Thank you.

Comment: Your answers seem to eliminate the absolute value symbols.

Comment: I don't know how this problem should be solved, please suggest.

Comment: Hint: Let $\lambda$ be the common value of $|a_k - k|$. When $\lambda \ne 0$,
show that the possible permutations are product of $50$ transpositions of the form
$(k,k+\lambda)$.

Comment: @vadim123, I use absolute value in case 2.

Comment: @achille hui, will you please point out the mistake in my work?  I can't figure out how the possible permutations are product of those 50 transpositions, please explain in more details.Thank you.

Comment: @carat you have included a lot of false positives. e.g. $1$ and $1+a$ cannot both belong to $\{ i_1, \ldots, i_{50} \}$ or both belong to $\{ i_{51}, \ldots, i_{100} \}$.

Comment: @achille hui, I see now. Thank you. I've read the definition of "Transposition" in Wolfram Math World, but still don't understand the meaning of "transpositions of the form...". Will you please give me example for small numbers ?

Comment: @carat e.g. the permutation $(1,2,3,4,5,6) \to (4,5,6,1,2,3)$ can be rewritten as a product of $3$ transpositions: $(14)(25)(36)$. $1$ get mapped to $4$, $4$ mapped back to $1$, $2$ get mapped to $5$, $5$ mapped back to $2$, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be the common value of $|a_k - k|$.

There are totally $7$ possible permutations, one for each
$\lambda$ from the list $0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50$.

When $\lambda \ne 0$, we claim that:

> Given any permutation $\pi \in S_{100}$. If $|\pi(k) - k| = \lambda$ for all $k$, then $\pi$ is a product of $50$ transpositions of the form $(k,k+\lambda)$.

To see why this is true. assume the contrary and permutation $\pi$
do contain a cycle $(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_\ell)$ with length $n > 2$.
WOLOG, we can assume $k_1 = \min\{ k_1, \ldots, k_n \}$.

- Since $k_2 \ge k_1 = k$, the constraint $|k_2 - k_1| = \lambda \implies k_2 = k+\lambda$.
- Since $n > 2$, there is a $k_3$.
- Since $|k_3 - k_2| = \lambda$ and $n > 2$, $k_3 \ne k_2 - \lambda = k_1$. This leads to $k_3 = k_2 + \lambda = k + 2\lambda$.
- $n \ne 3$ because $|k_3 - k_1| = 2\lambda \ne \lambda$. So $n > 3$ and there is a $k_4$.
- Since $|k_4 - k_3| = \lambda$ and $k_4 \ne k_3 - \lambda = k_2$. We find $k_4 = k_3 + \lambda = k + 3\lambda$.
- Repeat above argument, one find $k_n = k + (n-1)\lambda$ in general.

This is a contradiction because $|k_n - k_1| = (n-1)\lambda \ne \lambda$.

As a corollary of this, one can see that for any $\lambda \ne 0$, if a permutation satisfying the constraint is possible, then the permutation is unique.

For any $\lambda$ where such a permutation $\pi$ is possible, we can build
$\pi$ up by the transpositions:

$$(1,1+\lambda), (2,2+\lambda), (3,3+\lambda), \ldots$$

- At this stage, $1 + \lambda \le 100$ and we need $2\lambda \ge 100$.

  If $2\lambda < 100$, there will be a $k \le \lambda < 100$ such that
  $k+\lambda > 100$. For such a $k$, $\pi(k)$ will be undefined.
- If $2\lambda = 100$, we find permutation $\pi$ equals to
  $$\pi = (1,1+\lambda)(2,2+\lambda)\cdots(\lambda,2\lambda)$$
- If $2\lambda > 100$, we can fill in the remaining cycles in $\pi$ start from
  $$(1+2\lambda,1+3\lambda),(2+2\lambda,2+3\lambda),\ldots$$

  At this stage, $1+3\lambda \le 100$ and we need $4\lambda \ge 100$. If $4\lambda < 100$, we can find a $k : 1 + 2\lambda < k \le 3\lambda < 100$ such that $k+\lambda > 100$. For such a $k$, $\pi(k)$ will be undefined.
- If $4\lambda = 100$, we are done. Otherwise repeat above arguments starting
  at $(1 + 4\lambda,1+5\lambda)$.

In general, when $2\lambda | 100$, we have no problem to build $\pi$. 
When $2\lambda \not| 100$, we will have problem to determine the value of some $\pi(k)$. This means for any $\lambda > 0$, a permutation is possible 
when and only when $2\lambda | 100$ or $\lambda | 50$.

Since $50 = 2\cdot 5^2$ has $6 = (1+1)(2+3)$ positive factors. Together with
the identity permutation for $\lambda = 0$, there are totally seven
possible permutations (one for $\lambda = 0$, six for $\lambda$ being one of the factors of $50$).

Comment: Clear now. I've learnt a lot. Thank you for your help :)